# InnoDB, if every execution is a single transaction, then why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, transactions, innodb

First of all I want to say im pretty new to database stuff and the query im about to show you might look horrible in your eyes. :) But it's not the query itself that i want some answers regarding.

My problem is that I have a multithreaded server (using Google App Engine (GAE)), meaning it can open multiple connection to the database and run the exact same query on the exact same time. When running the query in "auto-commit = true", everything works, no lock wait timeouts etc. But when it's "auto-commit = false" then I get the lock wait timeout. See example below:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(true);
String query =  "INSERT INTO tblGameSession (gameID, createdBy, betAmount) VALUES ((SELECT gameID FROM(SELECT a.gameID, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, a.toc, NOW()) as timePassed FROM tblGameSession AS a LEFT JOIN tblGameSessionRoundData AS b ON a.gameID = b.gameID WHERE a.status = 1 AND b.language = ? AND b.category = ? AND a.betAmount = ? AND a.createdBy != ? HAVING timePassed < ? ORDER BY a.toc ASC LIMIT 1) as abc), ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gameID=LAST_INSERT_ID(gameID), status = 0";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt.setInt(1, languageID); 
stmt.setInt(2, categoryID);
stmt.setInt(3, betAmount);
stmt.setString(4, searchingPlayer);
stmt.setInt(5, GameSettings.getSetting(Settings.ExpireHours));
stmt.setString(6, searchingPlayer);
stmt.setInt(7, betAmount);
stmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
generatedKeys.next(); 
long gameID = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
```

This will get executed immedietly and as a small transaction since the table is InnoDB. But the example below will fail and cause a "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction":

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
String query =  "INSERT INTO tblGameSession (gameID, createdBy, betAmount) VALUES ((SELECT gameID FROM(SELECT a.gameID, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, a.toc, NOW()) as timePassed FROM tblGameSession AS a LEFT JOIN tblGameSessionRoundData AS b ON a.gameID = b.gameID WHERE a.status = 1 AND b.language = ? AND b.category = ? AND a.betAmount = ? AND a.createdBy != ? HAVING timePassed < ? ORDER BY a.toc ASC LIMIT 1) as abc), ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gameID=LAST_INSERT_ID(gameID), status = 0";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt.setInt(1, languageID);
stmt.setInt(2, categoryID);
stmt.setInt(3, betAmount);
stmt.setString(4, searchingPlayer);
stmt.setInt(5, GameSettings.getSetting(Settings.ExpireHours));
stmt.setString(6, searchingPlayer);
stmt.setInt(7, betAmount);
stmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
generatedKeys.next(); 
long gameID = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
connection.commit()
```

Shouldn't this do the exact same thing? The scenario right now is that 6 clients are trying to do this at the same time. Using the first approach works (actually too good) while the second approach fails badly. And I really need this part to be part of a bigger transaction.

So any ideas? :)

*(And for those who wonder what this is for:)
The query is used to get the gameID of a game that has been started. If it found a game it updates it's status = 0 (taken) and if it didnt find any game it will create a new game with status = 1 (free). The gameID that was created (or updated) will then be used to retrieve additional data for that game.*

Comment: Try putting the commit right after the executeUpdate ... and please add some stacktrace.

Comment: That doesn't work either! I will update my post with a stacktrace.

Comment: Why not break down this big and complex statement into smaller ones and putting them within the large transaction?

Comment: @tarik: I actually did that at first. I had the inner query as a standalone, using FOR UPDATE to prevent reads. But that also caused a lock and then it locked two tables instead of one. And I really need to join the two tables :/

Comment: It's possible this problem only occurs on the local (test)server.

I'm using Google App Engine (GAE) and as far as I can tell I get no lock timeouts on the live-server. Not sure what could cause this because the locks are placed in the remote database and not the server itself. So maybe the "commits" on the local-server never actually commits and therefore locks the database.

Still open for more answers regarding this! Thank you!